# How to change the order of date module fields on edit by language?

Tags: datetime

By default, when editing a date field that includes day, month, and year, there are dropdowns displayed in day-month-year order.  This is good for English, but for users whose language is set to Japanese, I would like to show the edit dropdowns in year-month-day order.  Is this possible?

I'm on Drupal 7.

EDIT:
I attempted to edit the locale format but I wasn't able to get it working.

Under localize, I set the following values for Japanese:
[image: long-medium-short]

I then confirmed that the field was set to display dates using the short format:

[image: field-display]

I then cleared my cache twice and reloaded.  However, the edit widget (a date field on the user profile registration page) still displays dates in day/month/year format for both languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across the issue today. Found there is an option to change the date format for Date field.

FYI: It is under "More Settings". Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Edit locale format in

```
admin/config/regional/date-time/locale
```

for different languages.

The widget is smart enough to adjust for you base on your time format settings.

Before:

[image]

Adjustment:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: I tried your instructions but I wasn't able to get it working... I may be missing a step.  I've updated my question; please take a look at it again if you have time.

Comment: arh, I just had another look. My original test was based on Webform's date field widget. It is smart enough to adjust accordingly. I thought Webform's date field used Date's module, but it does not. I was wrong enough to mislead you. I am sorry. My answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You also can easily change it if you don't depend on site-wide date settings. If so - just go and change "short" date format (just an order of days and months) at admin/config/regional/date-time.  Webform (and other #type = 'date' fields) will use the same order for its date fields.